# JSON append response with attribute from link

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, rest, zapier

I have and API endpoint in Zapier where I am calling all approved leave requests from a payroll system. as data.

```
    const options = {
  url: 'https://api.somepayroll.com/api/v1/leaves/requests',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${bundle.authData.access_token}`,
    'X-CLIENT-SECRET': bundle.authData.client_secret,
    'X-CLIENT-ID': bundle.authData.client_id,
    'X-STATUS': bundle.inputData.status
  },
  params: {

  }
}

return z.request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    response.throwForStatus();
    const results = z.JSON.parse(response.content);

    // You can do any parsing you need for results here before returning them

    return results.content;
  });
```

That gets me the following response:

```
[
  {
    "employeeId": "1",
    "requestId": 5487,
    "hours": 8,
    "leaveFromDate": "19-Feb-2020",
    "leaveToDate": "19-Feb-2020",
    "reason": "Birthday Party",
    "status": "Pending",
    "payElement": "Annual Leave",
    "leaveBalanceType": {
      "leaveType": "Annual",
      "name": "Annual Leave",
      "unit": "hours",
      "organisationSpecific": false
    },
    "payElementId": 50,
    "daysConsumed": 0,
    "daysCurrent": 0,
    "daysRemaining": 0,
    "quantityConsumed": 0,
    "quantityCurrent": 0,
    "quantityRemaining": 8,
    "additionalApprovalAcquired": false,
    "leaveInDays": false,
    "links": [
      {
        "rel": "self",
        "href": "https://api.somepayroll.com/api/v1/leaves/requests/5487"
      },
      {
        "rel": "employee",
        "href": "https://api.somepayroll.com/api/v1/employees/1"
      },
      {
        "rel": "payelement",
        "href": "https://api.somepayroll.com/api/v1/payelements/AL"
      }
    ],
    "id": "5487"
  },
  {
    "employeeId": "1",
    "requestId": 5551,
    "hours": 8,
    "leaveFromDate": "23-Jan-2020",
    "leaveToDate": "23-Jan-2020",
    "reason": "Camping",
    "status": "Pending",
    "payElement": "Annual Leave",
    "leaveBalanceType": {
      "leaveType": "Annual",
      "name": "Annual Leave",
      "unit": "hours",
      "organisationSpecific": false
    },
    "payElementId": 50,
    "daysConsumed": 0,
    "daysCurrent": 0,
    "daysRemaining": 0,
    "quantityConsumed": 0,
    "quantityCurrent": 0,
    "quantityRemaining": 8,
    "additionalApprovalAcquired": false,
    "leaveInDays": false,
    "links": [
      {
        "rel": "self",
        "href": "https://api.somepayroll.com/api/v1/leaves/requests/5551"
      },
      {
        "rel": "employee",
        "href": "https://api.somepayroll.com/api/v1/employees/1"
      },
      {
        "rel": "payelement",
        "href": "https://api.somepayroll.com/api/v1/payelements/AL"
      }
    ],
    "id": "5551"
  }
]
```

What I am trying to do is also grab the name of the employee from the link in the response https://api.somepayroll.com/api/v1/employees/1 since it is only giving me the ID number. Is is possible to cross link data like that and match on employeeID and get the data called firstName to be part of this result?

Answer (score 0):

it should handle by back-end however you can call link from response and get extra data,

Comment: Thanks, any idea how I might go about it?

Comment: send xhr get request to "https://api.somepayroll.com/api/v1/employees/1" in links varibe and see what is the response